# python can't find custom module

Tags: python, python-import

I am breaking a monolithic script into modules. I created a file called `standard_modules.py` that I use to import all the modules I'm creating.

Then in the script that has main() I'm doing:

```
from standard_modules import *
from standard_functions import *
```

Inside of `standard_modules.py` I have this line:

```
from list_users import list_users
```

I'm printing out my path with:

```
import sys
print('\n'.join(sys.path))
```

And I can see the path that my module lives in listed there:

`C:\Users\tdunphy\Desktop\important_folders\git\aws_scripts\python\aws_iam_utils`

And I have verified that my module file is there:

```
ls -l C:\Users\tdunphy\Desktop\important_folders\git\aws_scripts\python\aws_iam_utils\list_users.py
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        7/30/2019   4:30 PM           3256 list_users.py
```

My script that has the main function in it is in the same directory.

But when I try to run the list_users module, my script can't find it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\aws_iam_utils.py", line 122, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\aws_iam_utils.py", line 91, in main
    list_users(iam_client, aws_account, interactive)
NameError: name 'list_users' is not defined
```

If I put `from list_users import list_users` into the script that has main() the list_users function works.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get my script to find this and the other modules I'm creating?

Comment: If you put `from standard_modules import list_users` in your script where main() is, does it work?

Comment: Is `standard_modules` importing anything from the script where main() is?

Comment: do relative import inside the `standard_modules` like `from .list_users import list_users`

Comment: I was importing the from two files like this in main: `from standard_modules import *
from standard_functions import *`. If I flip the order and do this instead `from standard_functions import *
from standard_modules import *` list_users works!

Comment: @bluethundr You probably have circular imports between `standard_modules` and `standard_functions`

Comment: Ok makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @bluethundr In general where you have the problem where a module is imported without errors but stuff appears to be missing from it, you have a circular import somewhere. For example, module a importing stuff from module b, and module b also importing stuff from module a. The problem can be more indirect too, like a importing from c, c importing from b, and b importing from a.

Comment: ok got it. I will take a closer look at what I wrote. Thank you!

Comment: @JBChouinard is correct.  I tried to replicate your problem,  and the only time I see this behavior is when there is a circular reference within the modules you are trying to import

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change `from list_users import list_users` to `from standard_modules.list_users import list_users`

Comment: I'm trying to add `from list_users import list_users` to the `standard_modules` file. And then `from standard_modules import *` in the main script. If I add `from list_users import list_users` to the script that has main() it works. I want to import all my modules into the `standard_modules` file. I've clarified in the main post. Thanks.